# Direct Google Colab Links

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to get the direct link to a Google Colab file instead of its drive link?

Want the format:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb

Pressing share button gives this URL which opens drive on clicking.
https://colab.research.google.com/**drive**/1IZw9t1F47pjAL3LZU2Mrkl-sBiG3rT44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/drive/...` link is the direct link to a notebook stored in Drive. (Similarly, notebooks [stored in github](https://medium.com/tensorflow/colab-an-easy-way-to-learn-and-use-tensorflow-d74d1686e309) have a `/github/...` prefix.

Notebooks like `/notebooks/welcome.ipynb` are part of the service and can't be saved directly.

Comment: In other words if the drive link to a notebook is https://drive.google.com/open?id=18eifNzelHeV-BurqbhAYHRHCSBuk5i9D. The direct colab link would be https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18eifNzelHeV-BurqbhAYHRHCSBuk5i9D

Comment: If you use the share button in the Colab UI rather than Drive, you'll get a `colab.research.google.com/drive/...` link.

Comment: Yup. Thank you for the tip. The main difference I observe is when the notebook is available only when signed in to an organization account. Google docs in those scenarios presents a switch account screen and directly opens the document on successful switch. Whereas here we are redirected to Google Drive and user needs to push Open With Colab button.