# Links to local notebooks in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a notebook which links to other, local notebooks. Something like this:

```
This is a series of tutorials about X. 

Link to [Tutorial 1](tutorial1.ipynb)
Link to [Tutorial 2](tutorial2.ipynb)
...
```

This works fine in normal jupyter, but not in Google Colab. The links get resolved to URLs like this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/tutorial1.ipynb which is obviously not where this notebook is.

Is there another way to have local links that works in Google Colab?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717491) is similar, but does not quite explain how to get to the share link; see below.

Answer (score 2):

If the Notebook is only in Colab, then this works for my use case, maybe for you too:

- Right click on the Notebook in the file list view (see below).
- Select **Get shareable link**
- Copy the link, and use that:

  `Link to [Tutorial 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12bdw7VdhRhGFw2463wJ)`

(That's a made-up link so it doesn't work.)

On the other hand, if it's in GitHub, you can use the link this way — using one of mine ([in this repo](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/xlines)) as an example:

```
[My notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/agile-geoscience/xlines/blob/master/notebooks/11_Gridding_map_data.ipynb)
```

Here's that place where you can get a link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to force it to open the link in the same runtime as the original notebook (in the github solution)? It seems by default it just uses the default runtime, which is not necessarily the one I want (and as a consequence doesn't have the files that are created and shared by the various tutorials).

Comment: Also, while this works, due to the colab specific links, I would need to keep a complete second version of all notebooks specific for colab, rather than just one set that works on all platforms. A way that would not be colab specific would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you shared a Google Drive folder full of notebooks and data files, then it seems like the best way forward is to instruct people to open the other file from the Google Drive tab. That way you are all still working on the same copies of notebook files, which seems like the big advantage of Colab. It's not a link, but it may be the best workflow and it also keeps your notebooks a bit more platform neutral.

Answer (score 0):

This now works since [August 2023](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3877)